# A variable shared between views and initialized in AppConfig

Tags: python, django

I want to have a variable which I initialize as the application startup and to which I get get access from the views:

```
# my_app/my_config.py

class WebConfig(AppConfig):
    name = '....'
    verbose_name = '....'

    def ready(self):
        print('loading...')
        warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
        my_var = {}


  # my_app/views.py 

  def index(request):
    # my_var isn't accessible
```

I can't store `my_var` into the session because the session isn't available at WebConfig.

How can I do that then?

Comment: any idea if we have to use this variables in another application ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Define the `my_var` at the module level in the `my_config` and then import it in the `views`:

**my_app/my_config.py**

```
my_var = None

class WebConfig(AppConfig):
    ...
    def ready(self):
        global my_var
        my_var = {}
```

**my_app/views.py**

```
from my_app.my_config import my_var

def index(request):
    print my_var
```

Note the [`global`](http://www.python-course.eu/global_vs_local_variables.php) keyword.

Comment: we can initialize my_var like this "my_var = {}" in "my_app/my_config.py" instead of None, can't we?

Comment: Yes, you can use any value to initialize the `my_var`.