# Can you store a constant global object in Django?

Tags: python, django, geopandas, shapely

I am working on a small webpage that uses geospacial data. I did my initial analysis in Python using GeoPandas and Shapely and I am attempting to build a webpage from this. The problem is, when using Django, I can't seem to find a way to keep the shape file stored as a constant object. Each time a request is made to do operations on the shapefile, I need to load the data from source. This takes something like 6 seconds while a standard dataframe deep copy `df.copy()` would take fractions of a second. Is there a way I can store a dataframe in Django that can be accessed and deep copied by the views without re-reading the shapefile?

Comment: How are you running Django exactly? In typical use it should stay running and should be able to store objects in memory. How are you "storing" it?

Comment: Currently, I just have a post request calling a function that loads the dataframe from file, filters it based on the request, and returns the information needed. The file is never really stored in memory as it is loaded on the function call. I guess I am most confused on where I would actually be able to instantiate an object in a django project that I could ensure would be instantiated at runtime and will be accessible by my request.

Comment: I usually set variables like this in the AppConfig's ready method.
This SO question goes over this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28907933/a-variable-shared-between-views-and-initialized-in-appconfig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the nature of Django, global variables to not really work that well. I solved this problem in two different ways. The first was to just use django sessions. This way, the object you wanted to store globally now only needs to be loaded once per session on your website. Second and more efficient option is to use a cache server, either Redis or memcached. This will allow you to store and get your objects very quickly across all of your sessions and will increase performance the most.